# Aiming Netbeans code snippets

Tags: java, netbeans

Not quite sure whether I'm using the right terminology here, but Netbeans has a very nice feature where e.g. if you start typing `for` it will offer to write a code fragment looping over an array or list, basing it on the name and type of an array or list variable actually in scope.

If more than one such variable is in scope it will guess, sometimes correctly and sometimes not.

Is there a way to aim this feature at the correct array/list variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that like this:

- Type **fore** and press **TAB**. This will generate the for each loop.
- The loop variable is selected. Press **TAB** again to select the list variable.
- Finally, press **CTRL+SPACE**, select a different list variable, and press **ENTER**.

(Tested with Netbeans 8.0)

Answer (score 0):

In netbeans terminology, it is called code templates (many editors call it code snippets). You can customize them also by going to tools > options > editor and select required language from the dropdow.